# Make nodes executable

Tags: ros, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

Must I only make nodes executable which I create by myself (for example like this: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29), or also the nodes which I have downloaded in a package from ROS? Or should the last one are automatically executable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60346/make-nodes-executable/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To provide another type of answer for the question..

If you're using a compiled language, then the compiler (and the build system) should take care of the all of the details. If using an interpreted language, the a little more work is required.

If the first line of the node is set to the needed [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability) e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python`,

and

the file is converted to an executable by changing the file properties e.g. `chmod 755 filename` (See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) and other places on the web for details about chmod),

then the node will be executable.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those installed from binary repositories should have executables already (except for meta packages). If it is a source package, then you have to compile it first with either `rosmake` or `catkin_make` depending on its type. Compiler will set the file mode to executable automatically. For the Python scripts you have to manually set executable flag, otherwise `rosrun` will not find it.

To run a node (executable) always use `rosrun` and do not run it manually.

EDIT: as Martin pointed out, using `rosrun` is not mandatory. However it may help to understand if environment is misconfigured. For instance, `rosrun` will give an error if package is not on `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` in case you forgot to source `setup.sh` of your workspace etc.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-10**:
Why always use `rosrun`? Running it via `rosrun` is more convenient, but directly running the node from the command line is just the same.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-04-10**:
Probably I formulate it wrongly, but the point is that `rosrun` help to highlight problems with environment, if tab-completion doesn't work, for example. So for those who just have started to work with ROS it is better to have such a habit.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-10**:
Okay, seems I misunderstood you. Thanks for clearing it up. :-)